# javascript/typescript - force to pass object as function argument by eslint rule

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Is it possible to force the following rule by eslint?

- if the number of function arguments is more than one, use "object" as an argument.

For example,

- good

  - const f = (x: string) => ...
  - const f = (x: {id: string}) => ...
  - const f = (x: {id: string; name: string}) => ...
- bad

  - const f= (x: string; y: string) => ...

I checked the official document ( https://eslint.org/docs/rules/ ), but I couldn't find appropriate rules.
I wonder if some kind of custom rules can realize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max-params` rule. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-params Set the `max` value to `1`.

Comment: When I try this, I start getting errors for accessing the parameters of prototype functions like .map(item, index) etc.

Is there no way to only have it target function declarations??

Comment: Technically, there is no function declaration in JavaScript; both are function definitions. I think you meant to disable it for callbacks. The closest thing I could find was this GitHub issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9562#issuecomment-353753269. In this issue, it is mentioned that you can extend this eslint rule and filter out the pointers to callbacks.